# Calendar API v3 - Handling Deleted Events For One-Way Sync

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using Google Calendar API v3 to work a one-way sync from another calendar system to a Google calendar, and wondering - how should I be treating deleted Google calendar events that are not deleted in the other calendar system?

The 'cancelled'/deleted Google calendar event I attempted to update contains the ICalUID value from an event in the other calendar system (where the event is not deleted). When I try to update/revive the 'cancelled' event I get a "403: Forbidden" response, and when I try to insert a new event using that ICalUID I receive a "duplicate" event error response.

Is there any way to revive the 'cancelled' event or clear its ICalUID? Or maybe a known gotchya hidden somewhere within this scenario that I missed?

I can re-create them using a different ICalUID, but I'm hoping someone else can offer some insight from their experience before I abandon the ICalUID. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [Events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) resource, you can't update a deleted Event. You can, however, update a cancelled Event. ['Events: update'](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) will require the `calendarId` and `eventId` with the JSON object (updated `status` value) in the response body.

Comment: I would just add that the new status should be "confirmed".

Comment: Thanks for the info @adjuremods . The deleted events causing the 403: Forbidden error response have a status of 'cancelled'. Do you know how to determine, ahead of an attempted update, whether or not an event is deleted? I am acquiring these deleted items using the events.list example here [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync) but setting ShowDeleted to True and SingleEvents = false.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is struggling with this, we were able to solve this by doing a couple of key things:

1. Creating events using iCalUID instead of id
2. Add events using google's calendar.events.import method rather than calendar.events.insert. This helped to avoid the "403: Forbidden" response

This worked for us, so hopefully it'll help someone else!